# AWS EFS setup for general site, throughput concerns

Tags: php, apache, amazon-aws

I want to use AWS EFS combo to setup a site with 2 EC2 instances reading off an EFS drive.  My site is basic, Php Mvc ( all dynamic content ), 20 MB of files spanning templates ( + users templates ), css, js, images and videos. The idea is the images/videos are going to grow ( e.g. upto 2 GB per user ).

I'm really confused about bandwidth and costs with EFS. From my understanding, this setup ( due to the initial project size ) will have a default data throughput ( EFS to EC2 ) of 50kb/s. I must be wrong but shouldn't this be faster than dial-up in the 90s? With moderate traffic, loading time for images/css and pages in general will take several seconds to load.

I can add additional MBs towards the throughput but this seems very expensive to achieve adequate throughput ( $6/1MB/s ). I don't even know what is considered acceptable throughput for a site with moderate/heavy traffic... Does anyone have experience with setting up EC2 instances with EFS for small 20MB projects and measuring parallel connections?

I don't want to go ahead with a setup like this and discover I made the wrong choice once customers start using it.  Should I be looking at a basic vm provider for hosting? I'm hoping I read/interpreted something incorrectly. Appreciate any help!